# Reserve proxy to different locations based on URL subpath

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have different services that will handle different parts of the URL depending on the params being passed

Service `offer` will handle the route `/offer/44` and other routes like `/offer/44/calculator` the following code successfully handles that.

```
 location ^~ /offer {
            location ^~ /offer {
                rewrite ^/offer/(.*)$ /offer/$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
            }
        }
```

But my extra layer of complexity comes when I have the url `/offer/44/payments/*` and that then should be routed through another service

I tried lots of different variants of nesting locations but nothings seems to work for `payments`. Tried to do something like the following (the redirect is basic right now as i was just trying to make it just redirect... but ideally i want it to take everything after `payment` and put it into the other service URL)

```
    location ^~ /offer {
            location ^~ /offer {
                rewrite ^/offer/(.*)$ /offer/$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
            }

            #my ideal /offer/44/payments/*
            location ^/offer/([0-9]+)/payment/(.*)$ {

                proxy_pass http://payment-docker.local:20000/init;
            } 
        }
```

So my question is: How do I make local nesting work so that if it sees the word `payments` after `offer` it proxy_pass to another service?

**UPDATED:**

to make it even more simplistic

Some of the things i've tried

It seems that what `nginx` doesnt like is the numbers

**This works**

```
# Example URL = http://localhost/offer/
 location ^~ /offer/ {
                proxy_pass http://payment-docker.local:20000/init;
         }
```

**This doesn't work**. as soon as there is a number regex it always returns `404`

```
# Example URL = http://localhost/offer/3
     location ^~ /offer/([0-9]+) {
                    proxy_pass http://payment-docker.local:20000/init;
             }
# Example URL = http://localhost/offer/33
     location ^~ "/offer/[\d]{2}" {
                    proxy_pass http://payment-docker.local:20000/init;
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this ? As far as I can remember, nginX uses the longest match for locations with regexp.

```
location /offer {
            rewrite ^/offer/(.*)$ /offer/$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        }

#my ideal /offer/44/payments/*
location ~ ^/offer/([0-9]+)/payment/(.*)$ {
            rewrite ^/offer/([0-9]+)/payment/(.*)$ /init/payment/$2 break;
            proxy_pass http://payment-docker.local:20000;
        }
```

Comment: i get the following error `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:47` its to do with the location `~ ^` that should be `^~` . But even when i change that and the `payment` route doesnt redirect. worth noticing the numbers can be '1', '11', '112'. aka 1-3 digits

Comment: Same issue. forget abut the first route. is the route with the number the issue. Even when i try something like `location ^~ /offer/([0-9]+) {` and a simple `proxy_pass` with no `rewrite ` doesnt' work. The issue is that it doesn't like the regex with numbers for whatever reason

Comment: Of course it does not like them - the operation `^~` means `The best non-regex match`. If you need regexp - then you should stick to `~` (for case-sensitive matching) or `~*` (for case-insensitive matching). The first route does not need regexp at all. And the second route uses the resulting URI from `rewrite` for the `proxy_pass`

Comment: but even on your `location ~ ^/offer/([0-9]+)/` example and using it just as that for testing purposes. iit throws the error when trying `reload` the config as shown before. just as extra info I am using the latest version `nginx version: nginx/1.15.8` with just a normal install `brew`. `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:45`

Comment: But I updated the location block so that `proxy_pass` no more contains an URI part - and moved the URI on the right-hand side of the `rewrite` directive. You can also check online here - https://nginx.viraptor.info/